# Solve for $x,y$: $(3x)^{\log3} = (4y)^{\log4}$ and $4^{\log x} = 3^{\log y}$.

Tags: logarithms, polylogarithm

if $(3x)^{\log3} = (4y)^{\log4}$  and $4^{\log x} = 3^{\log y}$,

then how do I solve for x?

I tried taking log on both sides but after few steps I got stuck

Comment: What did you try so far? This site encourages learning and is not just a "solve my problem" black box. If you edit your question to show what you did and how far you got, you will get more answers...

Comment: Not only more answers, but also answers better suited for you. By the way, welcome to Math.SE.

Comment: I assume its log base 10?

Comment: yup it is log base 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take the logarithm on each side of each equation, the two equations become

$$(\log3)(\log3+\log x)=(\log4)(\log4+\log y)\quad\text{and}\quad(\log x)(\log4)=(\log y)(\log3)$$

Solving the second equation for $\log y$ gives

$$\log y={\log4\over\log3}\log x$$

Plugging this into the first equation gives

$$(\log3)(\log3+\log x)=(\log4)\left(\log4+{\log4\over\log3}\log x\right)$$

which, on moving stuff around, becomes

$$\left(\log3-{(\log4)^2\over\log3} \right)\log x=(\log4)^2-(\log3)^2$$

It should be easy from here to see that

$${\log x\over\log3}=-1$$

which implies $\log x=-\log3=\log(1/3)$, so that $x=1/3$.

Comment: thanx 
i actually tried this method but i had'nt split log 3x that's why i was not getting the  answer

Comment: @AmanGandhi, when you post questions here, it helps to show the steps you've taken.  That way people can see where you got stuck.  You'll get better response if you do.

Comment: i am new to this website 
in further questions i will take care of this thing

Answer (score 1):

I believe a hint is in order 
$$
4^{\log x} = 3^{\log y}\implies \log 4 \log x = \log 3\log y\implies y = 10^{\frac{\log 4}{\log 3}\log x}=x^{\frac{\log 4}{\log 3}}
$$
Insert into the other one. Re-arrange the first equation to obtain a similar exponent which should be $$x^{\lambda\left(\log^24-\log^2 3\right)} = 10^{\log^24-\log^2 3}$$
it should become clear.